# How to Download a file with Textcontent with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I was making a password generator website (which is for myself) and I was wondering if I could make a download button that downloads a .txt file and the generated password inside the file.

You can visit it here:
https://astr-ghe.tk

This is my generate function code:

```
//generate random password
function generate(){

    //set password length/complexity
    let complexity = document.getElementById("slider").value;

    //possible password values
    let values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+";

    let password = "";

    //create for loop to choose password characters
    for(var i = 0; i <= complexity; i++){
        password = password + values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length - 1)));
    }

    //add password to textbox/display area
    document.getElementById("display").value = password;

    //add password to previously generated passwords section
    document.getElementById("lastNums").innerHTML += password + "<br />";

}
```

Comment: So where in that code is the button and the file download?

Comment: You can probably use the answer here and pass the passwords you want as the text parameter with the function download() https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/10633285

Comment: @Bergi you can see it in here https://astr-ghe.tk

Comment: @Tzuyu No, please [edit] your question to include it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function written [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server) to generate a text file and download it on click.

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

And then call `download` as needed, i.e. inside `generate`:

```
function generate() {

    let complexity = document.getElementById("slider").value;
    let values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+";
    let password = "";

    for(var i = 0; i <= complexity; i++)
        password = password + values.charAt(
            Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length - 1))
        );
    
    download('password.txt', password);
}
```

**This behavior is blocked by StackOverflow, please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmw078k3/) for an example.**

Comment: The `download` function that neither of us wrote is the same, that's about it.  The JSFiddle plugs it into OP's `generate` function for instance, you just copy-pasted that snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Of yourse is it possible. You can just create a function to generate a new anchor tag with an Download Link to the Filename you want. If you set the `href` of the link to the encoded text you want to download, it'll be downloaded in a file named as the `download` attribute with an Content of the `href` attribute

### Demo

```js
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="download('password.txt','your Content here')">Download</button>
```